# Pygame renders text over old text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I have this following function to draw to the pygame window:

```
    base.draw(win, rocket.in_space)
win.blit(rocket_img, (120, 150))
if rocket.in_space:
    velocity_label = STAT_FONT.render(f"Velocity: {round(rocket.velocity, 3)} km/s", True, (255, 255, 255))
    acceleration_label = STAT_FONT.render(f"Acceleration: {round(rocket.acceleration, 3)} km/s^2", True, (255, 255, 255))
    altitude_label = STAT_FONT.render(f"Altitude: {round(rocket.altitude, 3)} km", True, (255, 255, 255))
    fuel_label = STAT_FONT.render(f"Fuel: {round(rocket.fuel, 2)} kg", True, (255, 255, 255))
    time_label = STAT_FONT.render(f"Time: {round(rocket.time_passed, 2)} s", True, (255, 255, 255))
else:
    velocity_label = STAT_FONT.render(f"Velocity: {round(rocket.velocity, 3)} km/s", True, (0, 0, 0))
    acceleration_label = STAT_FONT.render(f"Acceleration: {round(rocket.acceleration, 3)} km/s^2", True, (0, 0, 0))
    altitude_label = STAT_FONT.render(f"Altitude: {round(rocket.altitude, 3)} km", True, (0, 0, 0))
    fuel_label = STAT_FONT.render(f"Fuel: {round(rocket.fuel, 2)} kg", True, (0, 0, 0))
    time_label = STAT_FONT.render(f"Time: {round(rocket.time_passed, 2)} s", True, (0, 0, 0))
win.blit(velocity_label, (0, 0))
win.blit(acceleration_label, (0, 50))
win.blit(altitude_label, (0, 100))
win.blit(fuel_label, (0, 150))
win.blit(time_label, (0, 200))
pygame.display.update()
```

And this code to make the background move:

```
class Base:
VEL = 5
HEIGHT = bg_img.get_height()
IMG = bg_img
space = space_img

def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x
    self.y1 = 0
    self.y2 = self.HEIGHT

def move(self, vel):
    self.VEL = vel
    self.y1 -= self.VEL
    self.y2 -= self.VEL
    if self.y1 + self.HEIGHT < 0:
        self.y1 = self.y2 + self.HEIGHT

    if self.y2 + self.HEIGHT < 0:
        self.y2 = self.y1 + self.HEIGHT

def draw(self, win, in_space):
    if in_space:
        win.blit(self.space, (self.x, self.y2))
        win.blit(self.space, (self.x, self.y1))
    else:
        win.blit(self.IMG, (self.x, self.y2))
        win.blit(self.IMG, (self.x, self.y1))
```

However, when the background starts speeding up, the text begins to render over itself. I'm not sure why this happens. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
The speed at which the base moves increases over time

[image: Screen freezes]

This is what it looks like when the screen freezes.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: It's a long complex program but the relevant parts are these and the fact that the velocity increases over time.

Comment: There isn't much more relevant code but I added a screenshot of what it looks like

Comment: I thought that drawing over it fixed that? Is there a specific line that does that?

Comment: I didn't set a background so I assume it is, but I would prefer that the background image is visible.

Comment: The background does cover the entire screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the computation of the y-coordinate of the background. The algorithm breaks down, if `self.VEL` is greater than `HEIGHT`. Use the modulo (`%`) operator to compute the y-coordinate:

```py
class Base:
    VEL = 5
    HEIGHT = bg_img.get_height()
    IMG = bg_img
    space = space_img

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.y = 0

    def move(self, vel):
        self.VEL = vel
        self.y = (self.y - self.VEL) % self.HEIGHT
        
    def draw(self, win, in_space):
    if in_space:
        win.blit(self.space, (self.x, self.y - self.HEIGHT))
        win.blit(self.space, (self.x, self.y))
    else:
        win.blit(self.IMG, (self.x, self.y - self.HEIGHT))
        win.blit(self.IMG, (self.x, self.y))
```